# True/false question Regarding closed subsets

Tags: real-analysis

Is  the following statement is True/false

For any closed subset $A ⊂ \mathbb{R}$, there exists a continuous function $f$ on
$\mathbb{R}$ which vanishes exactly on $A$.

Comment: Are you sure that $\mathbb Q$ is closed in $\mathbb R$? I don't know what your definition of closed is, or your operative definition of $\mathbb R$, but what are the limit points of $\mathbb Q$?

Comment: @MarkBennet   $\mathbb{Q}$  is closed set

Comment: What is your definition of closed? - I was using "contains all its limit points", but there are others. What is a closed set also depends on the topology - any set can be given the discrete topology in which every subset is closed (and also open). But I am assuming you are meaning the one which goes with the usual metric.

Comment: @MarkBennet u r right  ........ i    was  wrong ......on  usual  it will not    closed    actually  that    not  came  in my mind  before posting this question